# Phpmyadmin giving me sintaxerror on creating a procedure

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

just a quick question, on phpmyadmin this wors perfectly

```
INSERT into cuerpoacademico
(campus,unAcademica,clave,ano,des,nombreLider,paterno,materno,grado,nombramiento,desde,hasta) 
VALUES
(Campus,UnAcademica,Clave,Ano,Des,NombreLider,Materno,Paterno,Grado,Nombramiento,Desde,Hasta)
```

but, not this:

```
INSERT into cuerpoacademico
(campus,unAcademica,clave,ano,des,nombreLider,paterno,materno,grado,nombramiento,desde,hasta) 
VALUES
(Campus,UnAcademica,Clave,Ano,Des,NombreLider,Materno,Paterno,Grado,Nombramiento,Desde,Hasta);
SET out_param = LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

The only difference between the two statements is that i added the set line with the function, but it's telling me that i have a syntax error, and if i try to use individually, they work, but in the same procedure, they don't, any help will be greatly apretiated.

Comment: Do you have a `DELIMITER` statement before the procedure definition?

Comment: Nope, i didn't because i'm using phpmyadmin, I need to use it? I'm sorry, i'm just a little bit rusty on SQL and phpmyadmin.

Comment: I don't use phpMyAdmin, but I think you probably still need it.

Comment: All right, i'm gonna check this out.

Comment: Apparently phpmyadmin doesnt accept the delimiter statement, but i'm still looking.